# dojo widget won't emit event

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, widget

I have a custom dojo widget that I need to listen for an event on another 3rd party widget and then emit that an event with the event object to another custom widget.  For some reason, my custom widget is not emitting the event or the event is not registering properly with my second custom widget.

Here is the event-related code in my 1st custom widget:

```
onSelectComplete : function(evt) {
    // this custom widget inherits from dojo/Evented.  I've tried using this.emit and I've tried inheriting from _WidgetBase
    on.emit(self, "select", evt);
},

startDrawing : function() {

    //self._drawToolbar is the 3rd party widget from an API
    self._drawToolbar.activate(Draw.POLYGON);

    self._drawEndHandle = self._drawToolbar.on("draw-end", self.onSelectComplete);

 },
```

Here is the listener in my 2nd custom widget:

```
on(self._selector, "select", function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
});
```

For the listener, I've tried listening for `onSelectComplete`, `selectComplete`, `SelectComplete`, `selectcomplete`, `select-complete` and none have worked.  I've also tried using `aspect.after` instead of `on`, but that also didn't work.  I was able to determine while debugging that the `onSelectComplete` of the 1st custom widget is being called correctly.

I'm stuck...

Comment: while guessing the functions are part of the custom widget declaration, using `self` notation is wrong. When your browser reaches the code, your (global?) variable `self` may be undefined or initialized to point at another object. I.e.. Convert to `this` :)

Comment: @mschr - in my constructor, I set the variable `self = this`.  I do this because, I am also using jQuery in my application and jQuery doesn't handle `this` the same way dojo does.

Comment: Are you using `var self = this` inside your constructor or just `self = this`? The second case is setting global `self` which is very-very bad idea! You don't need no `self` in the code you have provided. Just  replace `self` with `this` and you are good to go.

Comment: 2Brian i see, its ok to use a masked global like var self. only pass the 'this' needed linked in a local function called _self instead would do the trick for ya :)

Comment: @Brian could you perhaps reveal the full javascript-file? in a jsfiddle.com perhaps? Set the jquery version and make a perm-link inthere and edit here

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I didn't provide the answer sooner, but I did discover a solution.

Instead of having my dojo module inherit from `dojo/Evented`, I made it inherit from `dijit/_WidgetBase`.  By doing so, my custom dojo module/widget now implements the `on` function.

So in my 1st widget I have an empty function called `onSelectComplete : function (evt) {}`, which I call when I want to emit the event.

And in my 2nd widget my code is:

```
on(self._selector, "selectComplete", function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
});
```

Comment: Is this requirement to have a function onXXX defined for the emit to work documented anywhere? I've been struggling with this and didn't see this facet discussed. (And thanks, it was just what I needed to get my custom event working!)

Answer (score 0):

Do make things clear: The onXXX functions was the old way to emit.
I was fine with it, but it is deprecated!

What the hell is 'self'? Did you mean: 'this'?

Any widget inheriting from dojo/Evented can

```
on.emit(this, "select", {anyProperty: 'will be mixed in the event'});
```

The above is bubbling up which seems to be what you want to do ?

You could also do

```
this.emit("select", {anyProperty: 'will be mixed in the event'});
```

But this is only triggered once and not bubbled up.

From any other widget you can subscribe as you stated.
Tell me if you need a working example.